# Ignoring hidden files in Cweb

Tags: hidden

Executes the MIME change command:

```
find . -name "*.png" | xargs -I {} cwebp {} -o {}
```

cweb failed with error (for hidden files):

```
Error! Could not process file ./modules/._styl1.jpg
Error! Cannot read input picture file './modules/._styl1.jpg'
xargs: cwebp: came out with state 255; failure
```

How can cweb ignore hidden files?

Answer (score 0):

How about just not passing them to cweb in the first place:

```
find . -name '*.png' | egrep -v '/\.' | xargs -I {} cwebp {} -o {}
```